# remove browsers default focus from div element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I want to remove the browser's default focus (that looks like a black dotted border in firefox and yellowish solid in chrome) from div. I do not need to just hide it (which is by outline: none), because even if the outline is hidden the element is focused. `$(".myDiv").focusout()` does not work. I also tried to click on body to  remove the focus, but it did not work either.

Thanks

Comment: Afaik a `div` can't receive focus, unless its `tabindex` is set. So by removing `tabindex` attribute/property from the `div` (or setting it `-1`) should help.

Comment: @Teemu what if it already has focus, due to having said attribute? i doubt removing it with javascript would make it lose focus.

Comment: @KevinB If there's no `tabindex` there's no focus either, just save the change to the file.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB, it worked, if you could post as an answer I will receive it

Comment: @Teemu, actually I was using bootstrap, and u were right, the tabindex was set, but it was -1 and after all the item was selected, but `blur ` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: that's too short to be an answer.

Comment: Looks like removing `tabindex` attribute programmatically works in IE and Chrome, but not in FF.

Comment: @KevinB, Honestly I do not care, just thought, that could save someone a little time and effort...

Comment: @Teemu, yes, and I checked it by ff only, and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Do you need another element other than that div to receive the focus when the pages loads or you want no focus at all? what specifically are you trying to accomplish?